# CI/CD ADF Synapse - Modify URL in Key Vault Linked service

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-keyvault, azure-synapse

We use Synapse git Integration to deploy artifacts such as linked services generated by a Data Warehouse automation tool (JSON files)
It is different then deploying ARM template in ADF.

We created one Azure Key Vault (AKV) per environment so we do have an Azure Key Vault LinkedService in each environment and the linked services has the same name. But each AKV as his own URL so we need to change the URL in the deployed linked services during the CI/CD process.

I read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/cicd/continuous-integration-deployment#use-custom-parameters-of-the-workspace-template

I think I need to create a template to change  "Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/linkedServices"
But I didn't find any example on how to modify the KV url parameters.
Here is the linked services I want to modify,https://myKeyVaultDev.vault.azure.net as to be changed when deploying

```
{
  "name": "myKeyVault",
  "properties": {
    "type": "AzureKeyVault",
    "typeProperties": {
      "baseUrl": "https://myKeyVaultDev.vault.azure.net"
    }
  }
}
```

Not much familiar with the ci/cd and azure devOps yet, but still I need to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this using Azure Devops. When you create the Release pipeline within Azure Devops, one of the options is to "override parameters". at this point you can specify the name of the keyvault and the corresponding value. The corresponding value is configured in a pipeline variable set - which itself can come from the same keyvault.

You don't need to create the template. Synapse already does that and stores it in the publish branch (“workspace_publish”). If you look in that branch you will see the template along with the available parameters that you can override.

More info is available here:

https://www.drware.com/how-to-use-ci-cd-integration-to-automate-the-deploy-of-a-synapse-workspace-to-multiple-environments/

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/data-architecture-blog/ci-cd-in-azure-synapse-analytics-part-1/ba-p/1964172

Answer (score 0):

From the Azure Key Vault side of things, I believe you're right - you have change the [Linked Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/cicd/continuous-integration-deployment#linkedservices) section within the template to point to the correct Key Vault base URL.

[image]
[Azure Key Vault linked service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/store-credentials-in-key-vault#azure-key-vault-linked-service)

Comment: yes, my question is how to do that ? Hopefully someone in the world already did this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/cicd/continuous-integration-deployment#parameter-template-definition-samples)
Those examples are basic...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still are looking for the solution.

In order to parametrize linked service property and specially AKV reference, I think you should modify the template-parameters-definition.json, and add the following section:

```
"Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/linkedServices":
{ "*": 
  { "properties":
    { "typeProperties":
    { "baseUrl": "|:-connectionString:secureString" }
    }
  }
}
```

This will create a parameter for each linked service. The next step is to overrideParameters on SynapseWorkspaceDeployment task on Azure Devops.